# firebase method getRedirectResult not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am using flutter method from firebase signInWithRedirect(googleAuthProvider) for google authentication and immediately after that calling getRedirectResult() but the method never goes there or calls it. I am using predefined credential to get some form of result but nothing app just reloads from initial state

Here is my code

````
    // FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      await firebaseAuth.signInWithRedirect(
        authProvider,
      );
      credential = await firebaseAuth.getRedirectResult();

      print('Google SigIn successful');
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }```
````